# constants with same name in different files in java

Tags: java

I have two constants defined with the same name, but different values in 2 different classes:

constants_main.java:

```
public static final String FIELD_NAME_ID = "id";
```

constants_common.java:

```
public static final String FIELD_NAME_ID = "incidentId";
```

I'm importing both these constants in another class: and using the constant:

```
import com.example.constants_common;
import com.example.constants_main;
.....
Criteria.where(constants_main.FIELD_NAME_ID).is(inputId);
```

Here,the value of constants_main.FIELD_NAME_ID is taken as "incidentId" instead of "id".

What is the reason for taking the first imported(I'm assuming it) constant value even though it is qualified by the class name?

Comment: no, it looks like you specifically use `constants_main.FIELD_NAME_ID`

Comment: constants_main.FIELD_NAME_ID is equal to "id". Try to debug and you will see that.

Comment: I debugged again and now it's working as expected. Maybe it was an environment issue. Still wondering how because I'm pretty sure I saw the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to get the value `"id"` from the class `constants_main` try using directly `com.example.constants_main.FIELD_NAME_ID` without importing `com.example.constants_common`.

You will just have:

```
Criteria.where(com.example.constants_main.FIELD_NAME_ID).is(inputId);
```